# What's the best way to count streaks in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Please consider this array:

```
let tab = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

What's the best way to get "5" as the longest streak with "1" values?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by best and what have you tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to create a new array that either gets a `0` when `0` is found, or increments the last item in it.

Then use `Math.max` to find the greatest number.

```js
let tab = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1];

let streaks = tab.reduce((res, n) => 
  (n ? res[res.length-1]++ : res.push(0), res)
, [0]);

console.log(streaks.join(","));
console.log(Math.max(...streaks));
```

---

Here's an ES5 version of the code.

```js
let tab = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1];

let streaks = tab.reduce(function(res, n) { 
  if (n) res[res.length-1]++;
  else res.push(0);
  return res;
}, [0]);

console.log(streaks.join(","));
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, streaks));
```

Comment: Thank you very much llama. I really appreciate the ES6 flavour! :)

Comment: @LeSparte, but it's a little slower…

Comment: @LeSparte: You're welcome.

Comment: @llama, I'v tried to write the same code in ES5, but can't get it to work. I have an Uncaught TypeError. Any idea?
streaks = tab.reduce(function(res,n){
  if(n){
    res[res.length-1]++;
  }
  else{
    res.push(0);
    res;
  }
}, [0]);

Comment: @LeSparte: I updated the answer with an ES5 version. You needed only to have an explicit `return res;`, and it should be outside the `else` block.